# Can't run a Java file in sublime

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a Java file in sublime, but it will not let me run it if that file is within any folder in `myDocuments`. I was able to run it by moving the file out of any folder or into the desktop, but I'd like to be able to put it back into the relevant folder. Any ideas?

When I try when it's in a folder I get this message:

```
javac: invalid flag: /Users/dominiquedanco/Documents/College/U1/COMP
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Comment: The file is always in any folder but names are used in double quotes.

Comment: What's the any folder?

Comment: Sublime is a problematic environment for doing compilation unfortunately.